# Can android spyware access photos of my phone

Tags: android, smartphone, spyware

I have installed some mod apks on my phone few days ago and i am feared that if they contain any type of spyware then can they access photos of my phone?

Comment: Any app with a permission of `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` can read media elements and uploads them to web service. This is not possible in android 11 device because of scope storage.

Comment: Is it possible on android 10?

Comment: Yes, android 10 device still allows legacy permission. Legacy support will be deprecated from android 11 device.